# PHP Proxy Servers

Tags: php, networking, proxy

i was wondering if there is any way to turn my website into a proxy server  ..
i found plenty of scripts using PHP but they all require navigating to site in order to use
the proxy, but what i really want is a script that enables me to access the site via browser configuration like in firefox when you enter the IP and port number in the options dialog,  is there any kind of scripts that does that ?
any links may help me get quick on the subject are welcomed ..
Thank you,
AB

Answer (score 0):

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/
- http://www.phpmyproxy.com/

(and more, ask google)

Is this the kind of proxy software you're looking for? Just plain HTTP proxies in PHP.

Comment: those scripts are great, but i want a script that enables me of using the proxy server without surfing to the site and entering the site information in a form, some kind of listener script that listens for some port and accepts request, and relays them back to the client

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your adapter to this computer's ip and port, its synchronous though so it'll be slow.

```
    $addr   = gethostbyname('0.0.0.0'); //ip sensitive :((
    $server = stream_socket_server("tcp://" . $addr . ":8000", $errno, $errorMessage);

    echo "connected to: $addr:8000";

    if ($server === false) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
    }

    $conns      = array( $server ); // connections
    $connection = 0;

    // loop forever
    for (;;) {
            $reads = $conns;

            // get number of connections with new data
            $mod = stream_select($reads, $write, $except, 5);
            if ($mod===false) break;

            // I have no idea what this does but what im doing here is separating the client ip and port from server 1:1 only!
            foreach ($reads as $read) {
                    if ($read===$server) {

                            // if a client is connected
                            if ($client = @stream_socket_accept( $server )) {

                                    echo "\nconnection from " . stream_socket_get_name( $client, true ) . "\n";

                                    $recv = fread($client, 1024);
                                    $rec_arr = explode( ' ', $recv );

                                    echo hex_dump($recv);

                                    if(strpos($recv, "CONNECT ")!==0) {

                                            if( $src = @fopen( $rec_arr[ 1 ], 'rb') ) {
                                                    while ($chunk = fread($src, 1024000)) {
                                                            @fwrite( $client, $chunk );
                                                    }

                                                    $chunk = "";

                                                    fclose( $src );
                                            }
                                    }

                                    stream_socket_shutdown($client, STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    function hex_dump($data, $newline="\n")
    {
            $from = '';
            $to = '';

            $width = 16; # number of bytes per line

            $pad = '.'; # padding for non-visible characters

            if ($from==='')
            {
                            for ($i=0; $i<=0xFF; $i++)
                            {
                                            $from .= chr($i);
                                            $to .= ($i >= 0x20 && $i <= 0x7E) ? chr($i) : $pad;
                            }
            }

            $hex = str_split(bin2hex($data), $width*2);
            $chars = str_split(strtr($data, $from, $to), $width);

            $offset = 0;
            foreach ($hex as $i => $line)
            {
                            $line = strtoupper( $line );

                            echo sprintf('%6X',$offset).' : '.implode(' ', str_split($line,2)) . ' [' . $chars[$i] . ']' . $newline;

                            $offset += $width;
            }
    }
```